# Booting VirtualBox with Virtual CloneDrive mounted boot media

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox on a Windows7 64bit host, I want to use a WinXP 32bit on it as a guest. I have the installer image - legally - in a format (.img) that is supported by Virtual CloneDrive, but not supported by VirtualBox. So I added the virtual drive (H:) provided by CloneDrive to the virtual machine configuration as IDE CD/DVD drive.

When i tried to start it, it resulted in "Cannot open host device 'H:\' for readonly access. Check the permissions of that device (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)".

If I try to add the image directly, I get (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED) immediately.

Is there any way to get Virtual CloneDrive working with VirtualBox, or should I work around the problem? (Like converting img to iso, or soemthing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you try http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccd2iso/ to convert to ISO